# passing parameters from gsp to inside template gsp in grails 3.2.8

Tags: javascript, grails

I am trying to pass html tag from gsp to template gsp. But i am getting the desired value being passed to the template gsp . Attached the code:

```
**TestPassValueController**
package sample.test
class TestPassValueController {
def groovyPagesTemplateEngine
def index() {
Map testMap = [:]
def test = '&lt;H1 &gt; &quot; hai test page 123 &lt;/H1&gt;'       
testMap:[a:"one",b:test]
}
}

**index.gsp**
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<g:render template='testSample' model="[sample:b]"/>
</body>
</html>

**_testSample.gsp**
<script type="text/javascript">
var sample = ${b};
alert("hai");
alert(sample);
</script>
```

Thanks
Pooja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing b to testSample and changing b to be sample:

```
<g:render template='testSample' model="[sample:b]"/>
```

Then in testSample.gsp, you are referring back to sample now as b:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sample = ${b};
```

either change `model="[b:b]"` or change sample to point to `'${sample}'` and wrap it around quotes like shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am trying to covert '&lt;H1 &gt; &quot; hai test page 123 &lt;/H1&gt;'  to <H1> hai test page 123 <h1> using the decodeHTML() in testSample.gsp. Will it be possible to convert in the template gsp? because I am able to do it in the index.gsp and getting the desired output . But when I implement the same in template gsp its not working... Any idea?

Comment: two things to try, one don't pass anything in as model then it will model everything as was from main page. In theory bypassing issue. 2: decode  it on main page before it hits template if it is causing problem also look at ${raw(input)} as well unsure if helps in this instance